# How to reset aws RDS master password using python script or other tools

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, passwords, amazon-rds, reset

**Do we have any possibility to reset aws RDS master password using python script?
Any help would be appreciate**

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`modify_db_instance()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.modify_db_instance) to change one or more database configuration parameters including `MasterUserPassword`.

You *might* then need to [`reboot_db_instance()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.reboot_db_instance) to apply the changes.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: In order to **change RDS master password on aws** you have pretty nice options to perform. Modify the instance/cluster options/attributes using:

- aws cli documentation and modify the db instance / cluster https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/modify-db-instance.html
- python aws sdk boto 3 - https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.modify_db_instance
- changing it through IAAC tools such as terraform - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance
- Changing manually on RDS dashboard under modification tab.